Output Voltage Drop and Insufficient Current Consumption in a Full-Bridge DC/DC Converter
I assembled and tested the circuit shown in the schematic on a copper board. Without any load, I can achieve the desired output voltage of 400V. However, when I connect a 400W load, the output voltage drops by half, and the current is insufficient. What could be causing this issue?
Based on my research, I believe it might be due to not using an inductor at the output. I would appreciate hearing your thoughts on this.
Additionally, if you notice any mistakes or have suggestions for improvements in the circuit, I would be grateful for your feedback.
Note: I am aware that the MOSFETs I used are not suitable, but I had to use what I had available to conduct short-term tests at 200-400W.


What are your transformer specs apart from the turns ratio? Inductance, core size, core material? Do you see voltage drop at the input as well when you load the converter?

The two serial capacitors C7 and C8 need paralleled resistors to "equalize" their voltages ...

My core size is EE 42/21/20, material is N87, inductance is 6uH (under 100kHz/100mV test conditions). Apart from transformer details, I am seeing a voltage drop approximately 1V at the input when I load the converter. @RohatKılıç

@NafiCanEreli just to confirm, is the primary inductance 6 microhenries? What about the number of turns?

Secondary inductance is 6 uH according to transformer datasheet that provided me from manufacturer @RohatKılıç

@NafiCanEreli can you put a link to the datasheet or at least give a part number?

https://dosya.co/gnakrm7z0gzn/S22C-6e24072611230.pdf.html @RohatKılıç hope this link will work

@NafiCanEreli that datasheet provides slightly more than nothing. If this is an off-the-shelf transformer then it should have specified the intended application (e.g. 24-to-400V 400W half-bridge converter) and optimum switching frequency (As a comparison, look at WE's datasheets). If this is a custom-design transformer then you (or the designer) should have provided the transformer details. Anyway, I can't help further I'm afraid.

@RohatKılıç thank you so much for your valuable comments, help and consideration.


Based on my research, I believe it might be due to not using an inductor at the output. I would appreciate hearing your thoughts on this.

Inductor may seem unnecessary due to the fact that there's going to be energy transfer during both half cycles. However, whatever you have at the secondary, they'll reflect to the primary by the square of the turns ratio, so the MOSFETs see a "shorted" capacitor before turning on so it could be a problem for the MOSFETs. But if the net parasitic resistances on the secondary side (e.g. winding resistance) are high enough then that'd be fine, methinks. Using an L has its own problems, though, such as resonance/oscillations. But still better to keep an L there for smoother output.

Additionally, if you notice any mistakes or have suggestions for improvements in the circuit, I would be grateful for your feedback.

I see quite a few:

No voltage feedback. All I can see is a pot to adjust the duty cycle manually until you get 400V at the output. But this is not the correct way to me because the circuit is running open loop therefore is not stable. Anything can happen and there's nothing to stop it.
No current feedback. There are two on-chip error amplifiers but you kinda disabled them. You could make use of them as current feedback (though it can be difficult for a full bridge converter) to detect and possibly prevent core saturation.
Possible Volt-seconds imbalance. With the pot you adjust the duty cycle of the PWM signal, so you expect a proper magnetising and de-magnetising every half cycle. But I don't see any precautions against flux walking.
No isolation. 24V vs 400V requires good isolation. I see the primary and secondary are not isolated (judging from the same GND connections) From the OP: "There is a very little mistake in the schematic above, after seconder of the transformer, I am using PGND for diodes, caps and load" but it's unclear how you implemented the necessary safety precautions between the LV DC input and HV DC output.
Potential risk of having unequal voltage sharing between C7 and C8. Parallel, large enough resistors (e.g. 470k) across each cap ensures equal sharing.
No input capacitor.

If you give the transformer details I may add some other items.

Sir, I am going to switch this 400V by using SPMW module (module name: EGS002)in order to obtain 220V AC and 4.5A output. Trying to make a 1kW UPS btw. For this reason I thought I don't need any feedback because this module will do it. Before I use the module, I want to be sure if this part of my design works properly until 1 kW load. But I fail. For the flux walking, I don't have a deep knowledge and didn't do any research, I will take a look. There is a very little mistake in the schematic above, after seconder of the transformer, I am using PGND for diodes, caps and load @RohatKılıç

Without an output inductor nor OCP (over current protection), I’m surprised your MOSFETs even survived. You need to redesign your circuit, calculate your transformer for WCS (worst case scenario), calculate and include an output inductor, add feedback from the secondary and to survive load transients and shorted output/startup into a large capacitor, add OCP.
Staircase saturation of your transformer will also be an issue without current sense and slope compensation or OCP.

Thank you so much for your comment. Can you write the long versions of the abbreviations you use (OCP, WCS)? @winny
